# iterate over csv files and create contacts with attributes

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I currently have the below script that will create a contact with certain attributes I require.

```
New-ADObject -name SGTContacttest5 -Type Contact -path "OU=SGTestOU,OU=Contacts,DC=DC,DC=Company,DC=local" -OtherAttributes @{
'department'="America";
'givenName'="SG";
'sn'="Test";
'displayname'="SG Test";
'title'="Job Title";
'telephoneNumber'="020";
'mobile'="075";
'mail'="SGTest888@example.com";
'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'="Office Name";
'company'="Company Name";

'proxyAddresses'="smtp:SGTest888@example.com";
'targetaddress'="smtp:SGTest888@example.com"
}
```

This works perfectly but now I am required to input about 100 of these contacts from a CSV file. 
I get that at the top I would put:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\users.csv
```

Then I would then use this somehow:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
```

My CSV starts the same as my code the columns are shown as below:

- First
- Surname
- Full Name
- Job Title
- Office Number
- Mobile Number
- E-mail
- Location

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: How do I link the For Each loop in with my current code, so instead of the attributes being set statically they are set with variables from the CSV?

Comment: As you're using `foreach ($user in $users) {` you can reference the column headings as `$user.columnsname` eg `'mail'="$user.e-mail";` It is however easier to remove any spaces from the column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its a fairly open ended question, but $user in this example is a simple place holder variable, so could be anything, $i or $temp, it represents one interation of the parent, in this case $users.

**This will be a good start to see what your given back:**

```
$users = import-csv -Path C:\temp\users.csv 

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $user
}
```

**use:**

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
     $user | get-member
}
```

to see what you have to work with.

**Then you can access properties of the $user like so:**

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    New-ADObject -name SGTContacttest5 -Type Contact -path "OU=SGTestOU,OU=Contacts,DC=DC,DC=Company,DC=local" -OtherAttributes @{
    'department' = $user.department
    'Surname' = $user.Surname
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variables like `$user.Job` within the foreach loop. Notice that you should omit the quotes. Here an example with one property, you should be able to do the rest yourself:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\users.csv 
foreach ($user in $users) 
{
    New-ADObject -name SGTContacttest5 -Type Contact -path "OU=SGTestOU,OU=Contacts,DC=DC,DC=Company,DC=local" -OtherAttributes @{
    'department'=$user.Job;
    # ....
    }
}
```